# What is the maximum and minimum size of connection pool ADO.Net Supports in the connection string?

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, connection-string, connection-pooling, pool

What is the maximum and minimum size of connection pool ADO.Net Supports in the connection string.
Min Pool Size=[max size ?]
Max Pool Size=[min size]

Answer (score 20):

**Default Max Pool Size** 100

**Min Pool Size** 0

[Connection Pooling for the .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: @Saurabh Pool size has both max and min, the default max is 100 and default min is 0. So your comment "It is default size not max" is wrong and misleading.

Comment: @monotheist - The point that was being made is that its the "Default maximum", not "actual maximum". So, this highest voted answer does not  answer the question

Answer (score 19):

There is no documented limit on Max Pool Size. There is however an exact documented limit on maximum number of concurrent connections to a single SQL Server (32767 per instance, see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=SQL.90).aspx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx%29).

A single ADO.NET pool can only go to a single instance, so maximum effective limit is therefore 32767.

Min pool size is zero

Comment: I think you need to be clear that this is the MAX POOL SIZE and not the default MAX POOL SIZE. The Default MAX POOL SIZE is 100, but you can increase this to the maximum allowed by the database you are connecting to.

Comment: The link in this answer is broken, here is a working one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432

Answer (score 5):

Default value of max pool size is 100 and min pool size is 0

Answer (score 2):

The Default Connection Pool Size is **100** . You can increase the pool size using '**Max Pool Size**' property in the connection string. for example - **Max Pool Size=1000;**

If you are using the **Azure SQL server**, the number of concurrent connection will depends on **SQL Server Tier** that you are using.

Please refer the link for more information - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tiers